# Columnbreak is offsetting column alignment

Tags: multicol, columnbreak

I've a problem with `multicols` environment. Whenever I insert a column break, it offsets the vertical alignment of the two columns. Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\geometry{lmargin=1in, rmargin=1in, textheight=8.25in}


\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}
    With $x = 7$
    \begin{align*}
        3(7 + 1)^{\frac{2}{3}} &\overset{?}{=} 12\\
        3(8)^{\frac{2}{3}} &\overset{?}{=} 12\\
        3(2)^2 &\overset{?}{=} 12\\
        3(4) &= 12\\
    \end{align*}
    \columnbreak

    With $x = -9$
    \begin{align*}
        3(-9 + 1)^{\frac{2}{3}} &\overset{?}{=} 12\\
        3(-8)^{\frac{2}{3}} &\overset{?}{=} 12\\
        3(-2)^2 &\overset{?}{=} 12\\
        3(4) &= 12
    \end{align*}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

I would expect this to produce two columns where the rows align vertically, but it seems each row in the second column is off about 3/4 the height of a row.

Any help with this would be much appreciated!

Comment: Would you be satisfied with a solution *without* `multicol`?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\geometry{lmargin=1in, rmargin=1in, textheight=8.25in}
\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}
  With $x = 7$
  \begin{align*}
    3(7 + 1)^{\frac{2}{3}} &\overset{?}{=} 12\\
    3(8)^{\frac{2}{3}} &\overset{?}{=} 12\\
    3(2)^2 &\overset{?}{=} 12\\
    3(4) &= 12
  \end{align*}

  \columnbreak

  With $x = -9$
  \begin{align*}
    3(-9 + 1)^{\frac{2}{3}} &\overset{?}{=} 12\\
    3(-8)^{\frac{2}{3}} &\overset{?}{=} 12\\
    3(-2)^2 &\overset{?}{=} 12\\
    3(4) &= 12
  \end{align*}

\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image: adjusted columns]

Comment: Just don't ask me to figure out *why*. I guess there's a `\par` somehow at the end of the first column?

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is the trailing `\\` in the left-hand side alignment. I propose a different solution with `minipage`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\geometry{lmargin=1in, rmargin=1in, textheight=8.25in}

\begin{document}

\lipsum*[2]
\[
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
\qquad With $x=7$
\begin{align*}
  3(7 + 1)^{\frac{2}{3}} &\overset{?}{=} 12\\
  3(8)^{\frac{2}{3}} &\overset{?}{=} 12\\
  3(2)^2 &\overset{?}{=} 12\\
  3(4) &= 12
\end{align*}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
\qquad With $x = -9$
\begin{align*}
  3(-9 + 1)^{\frac{2}{3}} &\overset{?}{=} 12\\
  3(-8)^{\frac{2}{3}} &\overset{?}{=} 12\\
  3(-2)^2 &\overset{?}{=} 12\\
  3(4) &= 12
\end{align*}
\end{minipage}
\]
\lipsum*[2]
\begin{multicols}{2}
    With $x = 7$
    \begin{align*}
        3(7 + 1)^{\frac{2}{3}} &\overset{?}{=} 12\\
        3(8)^{\frac{2}{3}} &\overset{?}{=} 12\\
        3(2)^2 &\overset{?}{=} 12\\
        3(4) &= 12
    \end{align*}

    \columnbreak

    With $x = -9$
    \begin{align*}
        3(-9 + 1)^{\frac{2}{3}} &\overset{?}{=} 12\\
        3(-8)^{\frac{2}{3}} &\overset{?}{=} 12\\
        3(-2)^2 &\overset{?}{=} 12\\
        3(4) &= 12
    \end{align*}
\end{multicols}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

Instead of `\[...\]` you may use `center`, with the difference that a page break is not allowed at `\[`, whereas it is at `\begin{center}`.

[image]